# How to assign excel cell with string to array value in visual basic?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm pretty new to visual basic, but I'm having trouble assigning cell values to members of an array.  Basically what I am doing is looping through a column and assigning each cell to a new part of the array.  Test code is posted below:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim List(5) As String
    Dim celltext As String

    For i = 1 To 5
        celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Text
        List(i) = celltext
        MsgBox List(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Each time the message box pops up though, it is blank, meaning that the assignment didn't work.  The cells at those coordinates DO have values.  Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning to "celltxt" but reading from "celltext".

Add `Option Explicit` at the top of every module -- that will make these types of errors more obvious.

Comment: + 1 on Option Explicit

Answer (score 1):

1. When you `Dim List(5) As String`. The lowest element in the array is `0` and not `1`. You might want to change that to `Dim List(1 to 5) As String` else your first element will always be blank in the array.
2. You are using `ActiveSheet`. Are you sure it is the right sheet?

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim List(1 To 5) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i as Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 1 To 5
        List(i) = ws.Range("K" & i).Value
        MsgBox List(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also with to try:

```
Dim List As Variant
Dim i As Long

List = ActiveSheet.Range("K1:K5")

For i = 1 To UBound(List)
    MsgBox List(i, 1)
Next i
```

This will add performance by only reading from the worksheet once instead of each time the loop is looped.